# ion-input not working but input does

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

The following code works for allowing multiple inputs in a list:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="player in players">
        <ion-label>Player {{$index+1}}</ion-label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="player.name"></input>

    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

And in js

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.players = [{name:'Bart'},{name:'Lisa'}];

});
```

Each item in the list can be clicked on and a string entered. But when I replace `<input>` with `<ion-input>` (as I think I'm supposed to) the items no longer allow string entry, they just flash when clicked. How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 versions of ionic available, which are `ionic v1` and `ionic v2`. Looking from you controller code, I believe that you are using `ionic v1` but you are looking on `ionic v2` documentation for implementation.

Do note that `ion-label` and `ion-input` is a component introduced in `ionic v2`. Therefore, it perfectly make sense that `ion-input` does not work in your `ionic v1` code.

The standard approach of implementing label and input in `ionic v1` is as follow, which you can find in [Ionic v1 official documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#forms-placeholder-labels)

```
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <textarea placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
  </label>
</div>
```